# Flutter Admob Setup : A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

Tags: flutter, gradle, ads

I am getting this error while running my Flutter app after setup the Admob service to my app. Before adding the AdMob service the app was running fine. What should I do?

Error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\nazmu.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6ca6bfbb6ed79157a08fdd6548cc9e4d\work-runtime-2.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Screenshot:

[image]

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 30

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.bedtime_horror_story"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change the `compileSdkVersion` to 31

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ...
}
```